# Why does the regex dotall flag uses the letter 's' and the sticky flag the letter 'y'?

Tags: regex

What is the historic reason for these flag letters? It's harder to remember them when I can't connect a full word to a flag.

g: Global

i: case Insensitive

m: Multiline

u: Unicode

but

s: dotall

y: sticky

Comment: `s` is called `SingleLine` in .NET. But it was `s` long ago in Perl.

Comment: I guess `y` for stickY comes from the last letter, as `s` was already taken..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` comes from *single line*  (mode). One of the earlier implementations of regular expressions was provided in Perl (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)). See the following description from the [Perl documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) on the `s` modifier:

> `s`
>
> Treat the string as **s**ingle line. That is, change `"."` to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.
>
> Used together, as `/ms`, they let the `"."` match any character whatsoever, while still allowing `"^"` and `"$"` to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string.

The `y` modifier for "sticky" was introduced by ECMAScript in its 2015 version. We can imagine that "y" was chosen -- referring to the ending letter -- as "s" was no longer available.